# Не отображается название файла при отправке через PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Нужно отправить квитанцию по почте, подключил PHPMailer, вот часть кода

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';

...

$mail->addStringAttachment($receipt, "Квитанция.pdf");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->send();
```

Проблема в том, что не отображается название файла

[image]

однако если добавить не кириллический символ в начале, то все "нормально"

[image]

Comment: Не используйте никогда кириллицу в именах файлов, как минимум делайте транслит

Comment: Спасибо, я в курсе где и когда использовать кириллицу.

В моем случае проблема в функции basename(), осталось придумать как эту проблему элегантно решить